# Search option in syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer package flutter does not work

Tags: flutter, pdf, search

My goal is to use the search option on pdf, I found this package but I am having trouble using it, Do you have any suggestions for me?

1- **TextSearchOption** in `syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer` package doesn't work (it's not defined).1

[image]

2- Another case is when I use this option ( [Link](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf-viewer/text-search) ) in pdf but it doesn't work when I enter a text to search

Answer (score 1):

1 - In order to TextSearchOption work, you need to import the syncfusion pdf. Add `import "package:syncfusion_flutter_pdf/pdf.dart";` at the top of the file.

https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf-viewer/text-search

> Import ‘package:syncfusion_flutter_pdf/pdf.dart’ in the Dart code if
> you use the TextSearchOption parameter.

This will make the text  inside the parenthesis to be searched: `_pdfViewerController.searchText('the')`. It will show all the "the" found in the pdf.
[Here's a working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFLb6.png) of the code you show on your picture.

2 - The link also gives an example of how to implement a search bar:
https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf-viewer/text-search#how-to-create-and-display-a-custom-search-toolbar-with-the-search-features

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).